# What's the common name for this GUI element? (left-right box, assignmentbox, relationbox)

Tags: terminology

You often see the following element to assign objects of a certain type to another object.
We call it relationbox, but I can't find anything at all about relationboxes on the internet...
It's such a simple and well known element, there's got to be a well known name!

Here is an example (source: http://community.zimbra.com):
[image]

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852995/whats-this-ui-pattern-called

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems to be known as [**Dual Listbox**](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) or [**Dual Multiselect**](http://www.laurent-laville.org/index.php/pear/qfams/example?id=m1).

Comment: The only drawback I can see with this is the name does not work well if the "available items" can be added to more than one list of "selected items" (same control as in the image, just with several "right parts" (right listbox + buttons) stacked vertically).

Answer (score 11):

It's a **List builder**

Resources:

- [Designing Interfaces](http://designinginterfaces.com/) by [Jenifer Tidwell](http://jtidwell.net/), page 383
- [Windows Dev Center – Desktop App Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742407(v=vs.85).aspx#usage)
- [Balsamiq "Wireframes to Go" Community Library](https://wireframestogo.com/4abb-Column-Selector,-List-Builders/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_builder)

[image]

Comment: … which is a special case of a Dual Listbox/Multiselect.

Comment: The wikipedia entry says "A list builder, also known as a dual list, dual listbox, disjoint listbox, list shuttle, shuttle, swaplist and two sided multi select..". Good to know the generic term when looking for resources.

Answer (score 8):

We refer to it as a Swap List, specifically because there are occasional use cases where there are more than two total lists (as mentioned in the above comments). A good example of this is setting security levels for fields. Fields can be hidden, read-only, or editable.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to indicate the use of this term outside of your own team?  The OP asks for the element's "common name," and the other answers cite sources.

Answer (score 2):

A [related thread on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852995/whats-this-ui-pattern-called) offers some additional terminology for this type of pattern. There doesn't appear to be a consensus on what it's called, but I had the exact same question so I've been poking around looking for answers. The other thread has references to:

- [Parts Selector](http://www.welie.com/patterns/showPattern.php?patternID=parts-selector)
- [Slushbucket](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Slushbucket)
- Swap List
- Disjoint Listbox

I think "Dual Listbox" and "Listbuilder", as already mentioned, will probably yield the most results when searched, but wanted to reference the other thread in case it's helpful to anyone else searching this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Another term used for this is [slush bucket](https://www.google.com/search?q=slush+bucket+user+interface&tbm=isch).